# TSQL: Subconsulta para calcular un %

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Me encuentro con dos problemas.
En primer lugar, la subconsulta ya me genera un error que no soy capaz de solucionar.
En segundo lugar, una vez solucionado el primer punto, tampoco tengo muy claro cómo calcular el porcentaje.

Tabla [InParts].[Web].[Request]

```
Id  RequestDate
1   2022-08-02 07:36:20.000
2   2022-08-02 07:36:21.000
3   2022-08-02 07:44:05.000
4   2022-08-02 08:07:21.000
5   2022-08-02 08:07:22.000
```

Tabla [InParts].[Web].[RequestArticle]

```
Id  RequestId   ManufacturerCode    ManufacturerName
1   1           340                 PRASCO
2   1           340                 PRASCO
3   1           4965                JUMASA
4   1           4965                JUMASA
5   2           340                 PRASCO
```

Tabla [InParts].[Web].[ResponseArticle]

```
Id  RequestId   ManufacturerCode    ManufacturerName    Status
1   1           340                 PRASCO              Available
2   1           340                 PRASCO              Available
3   1           4965                JUMASA              Unavailable
4   1           4965                JUMASA              Available
5   2           340                 PRASCO              Unavailable
```

Estas son las dos consultas por separado que tengo y que devuelven resultados correctos

**-- CANTIDAD DE PIEZAS NO ENCONTRADAS AGRUPADAS POR FABRICANTE**

```
select resp.[ManufacturerName], COUNT(resp.[ManufacturerName]) as 'TotalPiezasPorFabricante'
from [InParts].[Web].[ResponseArticle] as resp 
JOIN [InParts].[Web].[Request] as req on req.[Id] = resp.[RequestId] 
where   resp.[Status] <> 'Available' and    
        req.[RequestDate] between '2022-08-01' and '2022-08-30'

group by resp.[ManufacturerName]

order by TotalPiezasPorFabricante desc
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**--PIEZAS AGRUPADAS POR FABRICANTE**

```
select ra.[ManufacturerCode], ra.[ManufacturerName], COUNT(ra.Id) as "total"
from [InParts].[Web].[RequestArticle] as ra 
join [InParts].[Web].[Request] as req
  on req.Id = ra.RequestId
where req.RequestDate between '2022-08-01' and '2022-08-30'
group by ra.[ManufacturerCode], ra.[ManufacturerName]
order by total desc
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se busca es que la segunda consulta sea subconsulta de la primera para poder añadir una columna indicando el % de piezas no encontradas sobre el total de piezas solicitadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que usando CTE ya podrías resolverlo:

```sql
with query1 as ( 
            select ra.[ManufacturerCode], 
                   ra.[ManufacturerName], 
                   COUNT(ra.Id) as "total"
            from [InParts].[Web].[RequestArticle] as ra 
                 join [InParts].[Web].[Request] as req on req.Id = ra.RequestId
            where req.RequestDate between '2022-08-01' and '2022-09-01'
            group by ra.[ManufacturerCode], ra.[ManufacturerName]
),

query2 as ( 
            select resp.[ManufacturerName], 
                   COUNT(resp.[ManufacturerName]) as "Solicitudes sin respuesta"
            from [InParts].[Web].[ResponseArticle] as resp 
                 JOIN [InParts].[Web].[Request] as req on req.[Id] = resp.[RequestId] 
            where resp.[Status] <> 'Available' 
                  and req.[RequestDate] between '2022-08-01' and '2022-09-01'
            group by resp.[ManufacturerName]
)



SELECT query2.ManufacturerName as "Fabricante", 
       query2."Solicitudes sin respuesta",
       query1.total as "Total peticiones",
       ((query2."Solicitudes sin respuesta"*100)/query1.total) as "% sin respuesta"
FROM query1 
     JOIN query2 ON query1.ManufacturerName = query2.ManufacturerName
     
     order by "% sin respuesta" desc, "Solicitudes sin respuesta" desc;
```

Comment: Gracias @isanchezo !! Con tu permiso edito la respuesta para modificar los nombres de variables y que sean algo más "fáciles" de identificar (al menos para mi lo son) Y porque había un pequeño error en la propia consulta, ya que debía terminarse toda la ejecución con un punto y coma que no estaba y también había que eliminar los "order by" de mis consultas originales, puesto que CTE no los admite. También era necesario eliminar el segundo "with" ya que forma parte del mismo grupo. En todo caso, me diste la pista a seguir :)